# Opacity messing up text

Tags: html, css

So I'm having an issue. I have a header, and text on the header. The headers opacity is `0.55` and the text is wrapped inside of the header class. Now here's the issue, since its inside, the text also gets the opacity applied to it. Here's what it looks like [image]. As you can see the text is kind of light. I've tried applying the opacity to 1.0 on the `ui li` sector itself, but that hasn't helped either. I've also tried the `z-index`, and that still hasn't helped.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="header">
  <ul>
   <li>
    Email
   </li>
   <li>
    Github
   </li>
       <li>
     Twitter
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.header{
    text-align: center;
    height: 55px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #EFEFEF;
    opacity: 0.55;
    position: fixed;
}
ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    opacity: 1.0;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-family: 'Avenir Next';
    padding: 10px 35px;
}
```

And lets not forget the [demo](http://jsbin.com/kazatayi/1). Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `opacity` on the header, set the background color to `rgba(239,239,239, 0.55)` and get rid of the opacity property all together

Comment: Well I'm trying to do it through opacity only. Is this the only way you can think of?

Comment: Yes, the reason this works is because the opacity applies to the element and all of its children, whereas the background-color attribute will only affect the background color to that element and leave everything else alone. If you want to use opacity then you'd need to remove the text from that element and create a new element for the text on a sibling or parent level.

Comment: Opacity will force all content inside the div to also have an opacity.  If you just want the header to have transparency, but not its content, then you can't use opacity

Comment: You can also use a separate element for the background, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use @Erik's solution (which is cleaner), or you can also add a separate element behind it: ([DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kazatayi/3))

```
<div class="header headerbg"></div>
<div class="header">...etc...</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headerbg{
  background: #EFEFEF;
  opacity: 0.55;
}

.header{
  text-align: center;
  height: 55px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
}
```

This might also be achievable using the `:before` pseudo-element, to keep the display a bit more separated.